# Module version mismatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

bcrypt seems like has mismatch with node.

my node version is 4.2.1

```
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 14.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:460:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at bindings (/opt/app/app/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/app/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/app/app/controllers/account.js:10:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (typically) have to recompile addons when switching between "major" versions of node (e.g. v0.10, v0.12, 4.0, 5.0, etc). So an `npm rebuild` should do just this for you.